# Downloading a file from a dynamically generated Blob URL

Tags: javascript, blob, bookmarklet

Summary: 
I am trying to write a bookmarklet that automatically downloads all my receipts from a certain hotel website. I'm able to open a new tab with the PDF showing, but having trouble actually getting that file data and saving it locally.

What I've done/tried:
I've been able to get the bookmarklet to traverse through the page, and find the right element, and even obtain a link to the PDF. I've also been able to open that link in a new window where the PDF loads successfully. If I put a settimeout on loading that tab, I can even get the blob URL as well.

The problem is - once I have the blob URL - I'm not sure how to actually save it. Also - I'm not sure I actually can, because if I try to manually open a new tab and paste the same blob URL in there, I get a 404 not found (which makes me think the URL is a single-use only.

Code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('aa-items past-activities--items')[0].getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click()
path_to_pdf = document.getElementsByClassName('aa-items past-activities--items')[0].getElementsByClassName('hotel-rebook')[0].querySelectorAll("[data-locator='hotel-bill']")[0].href
newwindow = window.open(path_to_pdf)
function checkLoad()
{
     if (newwindow.location.href.includes('blob'))
     {
          path_to_pdf_blob = newwindow.location.href
          console.log(path_to_pdf_blob)
          newwindow.close()
     } else {
          setTimeout('checkLoad();', 1000)
     }
}
checkLoad()
```

Comment: hi your code looks good .IT may time out error other wise check ypour it condition for satisfy

Comment: Hi - thanks. As I said in the post though, I'm able to get the blob link out - but what are the next steps?

Comment: sorry I mean check the url path_to_pdf by alert or place brake point  and in first line of code has a click event ,is there any function call